# Django - Drop down list that fills out the rest of the form

Tags: django, forms, drop-down-menu, autocomplete

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to generate form fields based off the value of a drop down menu. For example in the picture below I have a drop down menu that "Status" That can be changed to green, yellow, red. I would like it to auto generate the Text field with text like  "good to go" based off the "Status" drop down. (*note this is in the admin panel where you add data to the DB)

[image]

things I've tried/thought of:

I've looking into ManyToMany relations but I don't know if that is the right direction.

I also thought that I could just do an "if" statement in the model. I think this would generate the text the first time but not if it was changed from the user, is this correct?

Comment: you'll have to use javascript to POST the status back to a view, and return the new values to show in the other fields.